# How to execute batch file stored on server on local machine using asp/html?

Tags: html, asp-classic, batch-file

I am trying to execute a EXE file which takes numeric parameter and performs the action. The action contains Copying the files from server and executing on user's machine. I want to execute the EXE file when user click on the URL which will input this numeric parameter to this EXE file. In order to do this, this EXE file first needs to be present in client machine. for which i am trying to copy this file to local user machine when they click "Prepare for Installation" once copied, i have to use MIME type to execute the EXE file with parameter to finish the tasks.

Any idea how do we accomplish this task.

Comment: Are the clients on the same domain as the web server?  Are you a domain admin?  If so, you could fork a `psexec -c` process and have psexec copy the file to the client and execute it with one command.  See http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html for classic asp code, and Google for `psexec`.  If not, then this sounds suspiciously like you're trying to push malware.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to copy the file to the users machine without them installing it first. Sure you could do something with java or even activeX but it would be a big mission to do it.

You can set action of what a browser does with a certain filename extention, but you are not going to be able to do that with an exe file.

You might be able to create a new form of file extention, register it with the system and the browser so it executes the file but you will still get security issues on some browsers and you will have to do a massive amount of testing different configs.

I suggest you rethink what you want to do or give more details so people can offer an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works :

```
<button onclick="RunFile();"> Prepare to install </button>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("myWebSite/MyApplication.exe", 1, false);
    }

</script>
```